# how can I assign object properties to dynamic elements based on the modulus operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, templating

I have created a mini template that holds and `<h2> & <h3>`, I have created a loop that adds .inner everytime `i%2 === 0`, what i would like to do is split up the data being outputted to follow the same kind of rule so when `i%2 === 0` add .inner and also split the object properties so each .inner should display 2 templated object properties. Can anyone advise on how this can be achieved? Also my templated items seem to return undefined?

Demo here http://jsbin.com/otirax/13/edit

Comment: You should be using data[i].name, age etc. since you're looping through an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be improved in many ways. The selector here:

```
$('.inner').append(temp);
```

should actually be `$(".inner:last")`, otherwise it affects all ".inner" objects created so far. Better yet, save a newly created div in a variable:

```
inner = $('<div class="inner"></div>').appendTo($('#ctn'));
```

and then simply use the var, thus saving an expensive selector operation:

```
inner.append(...);
```

Another improvement is to automate template rendering. Consider the following function: it populates arbitrary {{tags}} from an object:

```
  function render(template, values) {
    return template.replace(
      /{{(\w+)}}/g, 
      function($0, $1) { return values[$1] });
  }
```

Complete example: http://jsbin.com/iviziz/2/edit 
. Let us know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

Templated items seem to return undefined:

```
var temp = template.replace(/name/ig, data.name)
    .replace(/age/ig, data.age);
```

Should be as below due to them being an array.

```
var temp = template.replace(/name/ig, data[i].name)
    .replace(/age/ig, data[i].age);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that thesonglessbird's reply was clear enough, but just to give a proper answer, instead of

```
var temp = template.replace(/\{\{name\}\}/ig, data.name)
    .replace(/\{\{age\}\}/ig, data.age);
```

you would need to have

```
var temp = template.replace(/\{\{name\}\}/ig, data[i].name)
    .replace(/\{\{age\}\}/ig, data[i].age);
```

you can see an example here http://jsbin.com/otirax/16/edit

Aside of that, schemantically a 'template' should not be placed inside script tags as it isn't a script.

Comment: hey this is really helpful thanks, 1 more question though. how do i ensure that object 0 + 1 are added to .inner(first) and that 2+3 are added to .inner(second)? at the moment 0,1,2,3 are in first then 2+3 are in second?

Comment: This is probably what you would want in that case http://jsbin.com/otirax/17/edit